# C++ unwanted pause in do-while loop

Tags: c++, input

I've been brushing off my `c++` with a college class, and I came across an odd issue which I am having trouble diagnosing.

The code compiles and runs ok with the desired result, but after getting a valid entry, the program seems to hang for `[ENTER]` before continuing

The program receives input which it uses to create a file under that name.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void createFile(string filename);//create userFile
void validateUserName(string &name);//validate user name

//main function
int main()
{

    ifstream file;
    string filename;

    cout<< "Enter your name and press <ENTER>";
    getline(cin, filename);

    validateUserName(filename);
    printf("validation passed\n");
    createFile(filename);

}

void createFile(string filename)
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open(filename.c_str());
    file.close();
}

void validateUserName(string &name){
    int errCount = 0;
    int i=0;
    do
    {
        errCount = 0;
        i=0;
        while (name[i])
            {
            if ( !isalpha(name[i]) )
            errCount++;
            i++;
            }

        if (errCount > 0)
        cout << "Invalid entry, try again" << endl;
        getline(cin, name);

    }
    while (errCount > 0);
    printf("validating\n");
}
```

How can I avoid having the program hang waiting for `[ENTER]`?

Comment: You seem to be missing some parentheses around the error check if statement.

Comment: `std::cout` is buffered by default. Might that be what's tripping you up?  Btw; why are you mixing `cout` and `printf`?

Comment: Bad structure here. Try to keep to one topic in a function. A validate function should just validate. If it fails, then return an error. The calling function then goes around a loop for more input. Getting more input in the validation function is just wrong...

Comment: cout will stay inside the program while I remove printf lines. Messy way to debug but it's easier on my eye.

Yeah... I know the code look bad. I'll probably split the function later once I get this code to work. Still have few more functions to add

Comment: @Rakete1111
Thank you! I can't believe I overlooked that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getting tripped up by your indentation.  `validateUserName` should actually look like:

```
void validateUserName(string &name){
    int errCount = 0;
    int i=0;
    do
    {
        errCount = 0;
        i=0;
        while (name[i])
        {
            if ( !isalpha(name[i]) )
            errCount++;
            i++;
        }

        if (errCount > 0)
            cout << "Invalid entry, try again" << endl;
        getline(cin, name);

    }
    while (errCount > 0);
    printf("validating\n");
}
```

And what we really want to concentrate on is the part of the do while loop

```
do
{
    //...
    if (errCount > 0)
        cout << "Invalid entry, try again" << endl;
    getline(cin, name);

}
while (errCount > 0);
```

Now you can see that if you don't have any errors in your input your still requesting input as `getline(cin, name);` is not inside the if.  We can fix that pretty easily by adding braces like

```
do
{
    //...
    if (errCount > 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid entry, try again" << endl;
        getline(cin, name);
    }
}
while (errCount > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your validation into a scoped block:

```
if (errCount > 0) 
{ // <<<<<<<<<<<<<
     cout << "Invalid entry, try again" << endl;
     getline(cin, name);
} // <<<<<<<<<<<<<
```